# Smudge adjacents textures

Tags: texturing

Is there a way to create a smudge/blend/blur type effect on 2 different textures on adjacent faces similar to the smudge effect in gimp?

Currently I have 2 image textures of gravel and asphalt on adjacent faces but they have sharp edges where they meet and I want them to merge more naturally. The end result doesn't need to have as much detail visible in the textures as the example pic and can be blurry like this...

[image: something like this?]

Comment: Did you try the clone stamp tool? I don't know the name of the tool in Gimp. You could try to ask it at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Haha nooo I want to do this in blender

Comment: Blender has a clone tool as well.